# Remove all special characters from a string except for digits and the degree symbol?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I want to remove all special characters from a string except for digits and the degree symbol °. How can I do this using regex?

I know that .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","") will remove all special characters, how do I put the degree symbol back in?

Comment: why do you not just put the degree character in your exclusion class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\W` and use a *character class subtraction*:

```
.replaceAll("[\\W_&&[^°]]+","")
```

[image]

Another way is to add the degree symbol to the negated character class you have since the negated character class matches all chars *other than* those in the character class:

```
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9°]+","")
                        ^
```

[image]

Tested at: http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/.

Comment: For some reason my degree symbol is also printing a circumflex, Â. Have you ever experienced this before?

Comment: That just means the text in ASCII was encoded as UTF8. This is a regular encoding issue

Comment: It's a pity http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/ does not generate share links. Note that if you want to keep `_`  in the resulting strings, you should add it as I showed in the patterns above. Else, if you should remove it from the patterns.

Comment: Hmmm I'm unable to remove that circumflexed A but I suppose what you've provided works for most cases.

Comment: The encoding issue should be fixed independently before passing the string to regex. If you want to keep `Â` in the strings, just add it to the regex - `"[^\\w_°Â]+"`. Or `"[\\W&&[^°_Â]]+"`.

Comment: I definitely don't want to keep the Â but removing it from regex doesn't seem to work. Seems to be attached to the degree symbol. I'm not sure how or why this problem came to be.

Comment: Could it have something to do with upgrading to targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 in my build.gradle?

Comment: No idea, you have not specified where the text comes from.

Comment: Oh I see what was happening. I was copying the degree symbol from a UTF8 source, probably online. I used ``(char) 0x00B0 + "C"`` instead and appended this to my String.

Answer (score 3):

You can use unicode character: `°` is [`\u00b0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm). So your regex can look like this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\\u00b0]+
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/ZgGdHj/3